# Condicional PHP integrado en un HTML

Tags: php, condiciones, email

Estoy haciendo una especie de "carrito de la compra" y tengo varios "artículos" como el del ejemplo, en el ejemplo solo puse uno, pero son 12.

tengo un archivo PHP que recoge los datos de un formulario en HTML. Dentro de ese PHP en el contenido que se recoge del formulario y envía por email tengo una estructura de HTML para darle forma a ese email. El problema está que dentro de esa estructura HTML quisiera poder filtrar los div, si el valor del input es igual o mayor a 1(uno) quiero que se muestre el div pero si el valor es menor a 1(uno) quiero que se se esconda.

Esto sería una muestra del input. Tiene dos botones para aumentar o disminuir el valor.

```
<div class="number">
<input type="button" value="-" id="minus-t2m12" class="minus" />
<input type="text" class="cant-t2m12" value="1" name="tr_2_12"/>
<input type="button" value="+" id="plus-t2m12" class="plus" />
</div>
```

Aquí les muestro una parte del código del archivo PHP. Tengo por una parte todas las variables y después en $content la estructura HTML para darle formato al email.

```
// ---- Correo donde se envía ---- //
$tr212 = trim($_POST["tr_2_12"]);
// ---- Envío de datos ---- //

#Contenido del correo ---

$content = "<html>
            <body>
              <h1></h1>
              // ---- Datos personales, etc. ---- //

              <?php if ($tr_212["tr_2_12"] >= 1): ?>
                 <div class='dato'style='background:#ffffff;;width:100%;padding:10px;display:flex;'>
                    <div style='margin: 0 3px 0 0;font-weight:600;'> " . $tr_212 . " </div>
                    <div style='margin: 0;'>x Transductor 2MHz 12mm</div>
                 </div>
              <?php elseif ($tr_212["tr_2_12"] < 1): ?>
                 // No mostrar nada
              <?php endif; ?>

              // ---- Más artículos como el ejemplificado ---- //

              // ---- Observaciones ---- //
            </body>
            </html>

// ---- Encabezados de correo ---- //
// ---- Enviar correo ---- //
```

No sé qué estaré haciendo mal, no consigo hacer que detecte el valor de la variable y ejecute correctamente el condicional para poder esconderlo si no cumple la condición. Solo me da error 500 al enviar el formulario.

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los errores 500 son del lado del servidor. Considera si no hay errores de sintaxis en tu código PHP (esta es una de las causas más comúnes que provocan error 500).

Por otra parte, tu código queda expuesto al menos a un posible *`Undefined index`*, si no se envían datos asociados al input cuyo name es `tr_2_12`. Para evitar esto, simplemente puedes sacar el valor del POST en una variable y luego hacer la comparación usando esa variable.

Por otra parte, te recomiendo que evites la mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML. Produce un código no solamente confuso, sino también difícil de depurar. Es mejor concatenar todo en una variable, la cual podrás depurar fácilmente. O, si necesitas esa información para enviarla por e-mail, todo se simplifica, porque puedes usar `$content` para el envío del e-mail.

Esta es mi propuesta:

```
<?php
  $tr212 = !empty($_POST["tr_2_12"]) ? trim($_POST["tr_2_12"]) : NULL;

  $content = "<html>
              <body>
                <h1></h1>";
                
  if ($tr_212 >= 1) {
    $content.="<div class='dato'style='background:#ffffff;;width:100%;padding:10px;display:flex;'>
                      <div style='margin: 0 3px 0 0;font-weight:600;'> " . $tr_212 . " </div>
                      <div style='margin: 0;'>x Transductor 2MHz 12mm</div>
                   </div>";
  }
  $content.="</body>
              </html>";
  echo $content;
?>
```

Otra ventaja de escribir tu código así es que puedes reutilizar contenido. Supongamos que necesites varios bloques con el mismo contenido de los `div`, donde lo único que cambiaría sería el valor de la variable. Podrías crear una variable con los div y un marcador y luego usar `prinft` o `sprintf` para agregar ese contenido repetitivo combinado con el valor de la variable cambiante en cada caso.

Comment: Hola, discúlpame pero no llego a entender como puedo seguir agregando bloques con contenido html. Por ejemplo, el que puse es "Transductor 2MHz ... " y ahora quiero agregar otro debajo, que sea la misma estructura pero con "Gel acoplante...". ¿Cómo podría hacerlo sin que me de error? Gracias

Comment: @JosepQuerol en PHP se usa `.=` para concatenar contenido a una variable ya existente. Si observas el `if` verás que se agrega el div en caso de que esa condición se cumpla. Así, puedes seguir agregando lo que quieras. Supongamos otro bloque condicional: `if (...aquí la condición) { $content .= "<p>Lo que quieras agregar</p>"; }`

Comment: En muchos casos es mejor usar un bloque `switch ... case` por ser más claro que los bloques if ... elseif y si lo único que cambia es el valor (los estilos y demás cosas de los div son iguales siempre) podrías tener el contenido de los div en una variable única y usar sprintf como te comenté en la respuesta. Así el código se hace menos repetitivo. Sea como sea, para que el código no falle es esencial que uses la sintaxis correctamente. Cómo ya dije, los errores 500 por lo general se deben a errores de sintaxis.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Entonces, si quisiera agregar otro bloque igual (siguiendo la estructura que tengo) solo tengo que agregar por una parte la nueva variable y debajo del 'if (...aquí la condición) { $content .= "<p>Lo que quieras agregar</p>"; } ' agregaría otro igual pero con los valores de la otra variable. ¿Es así?

Comment: @JosepQuerol Correcto. En todo caso si lo intentas y no funciona edita la pregunta mostrando la nueva versión del código e indicando los errores que tienes.

Comment: @a-caedano Muchas gracias, he conseguido que me funcione. Lo único es que antes, cuando rellenaba el formulario y clicaba en Enviar, me aparecía el mensaje "su email se ha enviado correctamente". Ahora, además del mensaje me aparecen todos los datos que se rellenaron en el formulario y se envían por mail, todo lo que se encuentra dentro de $content. ¿Será que tengo algo mal en el código?

Comment: @JosepQuerol si no quieres que aparezca, no pongas `echo $content;`, simplemente usa `$content` en la función de envío del e-mail. Aquí yo usé `echo` porque inicialmente no se sabía para que era ese contenido.

Answer (score 0):

Veo en el código algún error como usar $tr_212 como string cuando es un array supongo que será $tr_212["tr_2_12"]. Meter <?php dentro de la cadena que luego se va a escribir como página web no es lo suyo. Y el if en php no tiene endif ni los dos puntos. Te propongo esta solución no saca nada si $tr_212["tr_2_12"] es 0 o menos y saca el valor si es 1 o más.

```
$content = "<html><body><h1></h1>";
if ($tr_212["tr_2_12"] >= 1){
    $content.= "<div class='dato'style='background:#ffffff;;width:100%;padding:10px;display:flex;'>
    <div style='margin: 0 3px 0 0;font-weight:600;'> " . $tr_212["tr_2_12"]  . " </div>
    <div style='margin: 0;'>x Transductor 2MHz 12mm</div></div>";
    }
$content .="</body></html>"; 
echo $content;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Creo que no me expliqué bien de todo. Estoy haciendo una especie de "carrito de la compra" y tengo varios "artículos" como el del ejemplo, en el ejemplo solo puse uno, pero son 12. Por otra parte, cuando envío los datos del formulario, me aparece el HTML que está en el PHP, y no quiero que se vea, está pensado para enviar por email, no para verse en pantalla. De momento no pude solucionarlo.

Comment: No entiendo, ¿el formulario envia HTML? Lo habitual es que un formulario envíe los valores de sus campos. Partiendo de eso, ahora tu quieres crear un contenido para enviar por correo y sin HTML ¿Es eso?.

Comment: Sí, el formulario envía los valores de los campos. Pero esos campos, dentro del $content están insertados dentro de una estructura HTML porque necesito dar algo de formato y que no le quede una "lista simple" de datos a quien recibe el email.